# How to leave a line between paragraphs when writing text in the visual or text editor

Tags: editor, cms

I'm using the inbuilt text editor in Wordpress 4.0 to edit some content. I've got 2 paragraphs and would like to leave a blank line between the two.

To do this I could add a `<br>` element between the 2 paragraphs, but if someone who doesn't know html is writing the content this wouldn't be very helpful; is there a way it can be done natively in Wordpress?

I've attached some markups to illustrate the issue at the moment.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Try using 
`echo wpautop( get_the_content());` 
This will keep line breaks from your post content without using BR tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [wpautop](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wpautop), and in your CSS styles (editor styles + theme styles) make sure that any paragraphs are properly spaced.

```
p {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

or

```
p + p {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```